# Characterize matrices complying to certain constraints.

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

Characterize those matrices $ X $ (real symmetric), $ Y$  (real positive definite), $ R$  (real diagonal) and $ F $ (real diagonal) such that

$ XRY + YRX = 0$ ,   (1)

$ YRY - XRX = F$ .  (2)

i.e, can we give some explicit expressions (or give some properties) for $ X$ , $ Y$ , $ R$ , and $ F$ ?

From (1),  I can only derive that

$RX = MJM^{-1}$ and $ Y = M^{-T}M^{-1}$ , where $ J$  is skew symmetric and $ M$  is full rank.